# How to select multiple entries with the same value in one column in T-SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So, I am working in Visual Studio 2013. And I have a table like this:

```
id | fk  | data
----------------------
1  |  1  |  something1
2  |  1  |  something2
3  |  1  |  something3
.  |  .  |  ...
.  |  .  |  ...
6  |  2  |  ...
```

The fk is a foreign key to another table. I want to select all the rows which have the same fk. There is an undefined number of the same fk entries (there could be 5 rows with value 1 and 3 rows with value 2, etc.) But, I want to be able to switch said fk in my program so that when i put the DB in a Form in Visual Studio, clicking a button next would get me the next value of the fk. For example, I would like the first result to come out like this:

```
id | fk  | data
----------------------
1  |  1  |  something1
2  |  1  |  something2
3  |  1  |  something3
```

And when I click next to get me to the next entry, the result would be:

```
id | fk  | data
----------------------
6  |  2  |  ....
7  |  2  |  ....
```

Is there a way in SQL to combine just the results with the same fk value? All of the solutions I have found so far gave me all of the fk values (all entries). I haven't found a way to get just all the entries with a **single**, unique value in the fk column.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a basic [`SELECT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) with a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
  id, fk, data
FROM
  your_table_name
WHERE
  fk = 1
```

I can't help you with the VisualStudio stuff though, but you'll just have to repeat the same query incrementing the `fk` value in the `WHERE` clause